# How to restart gui application game e.g play again

Tags: java, user-interface, return

sorry for the spaghetti code! It is my first gui. Very new to coding in general. I know while loops can be used outside of gui but obviously not for this lol. So I was wondering how I can restart my java game in the "private void runAway()" method I made?

```
public class EnemiesAttackApp extends Application {
@Override
public void start (Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Enemies Attack!");
    primaryStage.show();

}

//System objects
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Random rand = new Random();

//Game variables
String[] enemies = {"Skeleton", "Zombie", "Warrior", "Assassin"};
int enemyAttackDamage = 25;
int enemyHealth = 0 + rand.nextInt(75);
String enemy = enemies[rand.nextInt(enemies.length)];

// Player variables
int health = 100; etc



 private void initGame() {
    println("Welcome to Enemies Attack v 0.1");
    println("-------------------------------");


    if (enemyHealth > 0)
        println("\t# " + enemy + " appeared! #\n");
        println("\tYOUR HP: " + health);
        println("\t" + enemy + "'s HP: " + enemyHealth);
        println("\n\tWhat would you like to do?");
        println("\t1. Attack enemy");
        println("\t2. Drink potion");
        println("\t3. Run");

        initCommands();
}



       `private void runAway() {

        println("\t You ran away from the " + enemy + "!");

        // how do I restart the gui here?    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be wise to create an object that controls the current "scene" and reinstance this object every time the game restarts. Anyways, here´s your modified code that should work:

```
public class EnemiesAttackApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start (Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Enemies Attack!");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    //System objects
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();

    //Game variables
    String[] enemies = {"Skeleton", "Zombie", "Warrior", "Assassin"};
    int enemyAttackDamage = 25;
    int enemyHealth = 0;
    String enemy = null;

    // Player variables
    int health = 0;



    private void initGame() {
        enemyHealth = 0 + rand.nextInt(75);
        enemy = enemies[rand.nextInt(enemies.length)];
        health = 100;

        println("Welcome to Enemies Attack v 0.1");
        println("-------------------------------");

        if (enemyHealth > 0) {
            println("\t# " + enemy + " appeared! #\n");
            println("\tYOUR HP: " + health);
            println("\t" + enemy + "'s HP: " + enemyHealth);
            println("\n\tWhat would you like to do?");
            println("\t1. Attack enemy");
            println("\t2. Drink potion");
            println("\t3. Run");

            initCommands();
        }
    }


    private void runAway() {
        println("\t You ran away from the " + enemy + "!");

        initGame();
    }

}
```

It basically follows the logic to have a method (in my example the init game) that resets all the values.

Comment: Happy to help.
If something answers your question please tag it as answer by clicking the little accept as answer button (left side under the up and downvote buttons)

Not just because it would be great for me but also because it marks the question as answered.